# Could not find images in .NET web application

Tags: .net, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I keep some html content of the pages to the database. According to situation I get the html of content from the database and put it to the page.

**Example content:**

```
<p>
Test Content
<img src="~/images/test.jpg" />
</p>
```

The problem is `~` doesnt work as I expected. How do I configure `~` to work as an absolute path of the web application any of files e.g. in .css, .aspx so it will be rendered as `www.test.com/images/test.jpg`?

**According to answers:**

I have a content that is on the database so the image' src or anchor' href is rendered just as an html content even if I add them runat=server. So what I should do is, before putting string to the aspx page, I should run a function and give this content as a parameter to it. Then put the absolute path of website any src or href tags where a ~ in it. This can be done by regex.

Answer (score 1):

For CSS content linking you can follow relative path HTML guidance below,

```
 ../filename  - links up one directory
 ../../filename - filename is located two directories up
 /filename - domain name root
 filename - file is in current directory
 folder/filename - file is located in folder sub-folder
```

For HTML in .aspx pages you can use,

```
 //WebForms
 src="<%#VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/filename")%>"

 //MVC 
 src="<%=Url.Content("~/filename")%>"
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the "~" you can always point to the root of the website by using "/"

So just

```
<p>
Test Content
<img src="/images/test.jpg" />
</p>
```

Comment: If requested page is something like www.test.com/article/this-is-good then your example will point to the www.test.com/article/images/test.jpg not to www.test.com/images/test.jpg

Comment: no it won't. it'll be just fine. begining slash stands for root.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the

> runat=server

-attribute to the img

Comment: This is actually working if the  img is already in the aspx page. But what did here is putting html content as a string so ~ doest have a meaning as a server side control.